# Knight's Tour Printing Out List of Moves (Recursion)

Tags: c++, list, recursion, boolean, knights-tour

```
#include "knight.h"
#include <iostream>
bool voyagingKnight(Grid& visited, int x, int y, int m);
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Grid visited;
    int m =0;
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    voyagingKnight(visited, x, y, m);

    return 0;
}

bool voyagingKnight(Grid& visited, int x, int y, int m){

    //Ensure that the cell is in bounds.
    if (x>=visited.getWidth() || x<0 || y>=visited.getHeight() || y<0){
        return false;
    }

    //Ensure that the cell is untouched.
    if(visited[x][y] != -1 && m != 0){
        return false;
    }

    //If the iteration has made it this far then it is a valid move.
    visited[x][y] = m;

    //If all cells have been touched, output the board and exit the function.
    if(m == visited.getWidth() * visited.getHeight() - 1){

        //Loop through each row.
        for (int i = 0; i < visited.getHeight(); i++){
            //Loop through each column
            for (int j = 0; j < visited.getWidth(); j++){
                //Output each cell.
                std::cout << visited[j][i];

                //If the value is 1 didget, use 4 spaces, else use only 3.
                if (visited[j][i] < 10) std::cout << "    ";
                else std::cout << "   ";

            }
            //Add a space at the end of every row.
            std::cout << "\n";
        }

        return true;

        //Else, the move was valid, but the voyage is not yet complete.
    }else{
        bool result = false;

        //Recursively call each move to check for validity.
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x+2, y+1, m+1));
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x+2, y-1, m+1));
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x-2, y+1, m+1));
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x-2, y-1, m+1));
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x+1, y+2, m+1));
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x+1, y-2, m+1));
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x-1, y+2, m+1));
        result = (result || voyagingKnight(visited, x-1, y-2, m+1));

        //This position resulted in a voyage.
        if( result == true ){
            return true;
            //Else, not of the moves were sucessfull, so we must backtrack.
        }else{
            //Unviset the current location.
            visited[x][y] = -1;
            return false;
        }
    }
}


getMoves(int i, int j) {
    // How do I print out the list of moves?
    // Also what should I be returning? A string everytime?

}
```

I'm not looking for a direct answer, just some guidance on how to proceed. I believe that my program works because it compiles and runs without errors however I am not completely sure since I can't print out the moves. Any other insights about my program are appreciated and welcomed. Much thanks in advance.